# Can't get around index out of range error

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a code to format a series of strings (I posted this a little bit earlier but deleted it a few minutes later because I thought I didn't put enough effort in). I'm re-posting now because I keep getting an "index out of range" error, but am unsure how to fix it.

I've tried wrapping everything I could think of in "if" statements that SHOULD prevent out of range errors, but they aren't helping!

Do you see what's wrong?

(FYI: ExpressionTools.isOp(char) is a method that returns true or false depending on whether the character in question is an operator or not aka: +, -, *, / )

```
public static List<String> postfix = new ArrayList<String>();

public static String result; // the result of corrected string

// corrects formating in postfix string if any errors, enters into postfix
// array
public static void spaces(String a, int x) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(a);

    for (int i = x; i < b.length(); i++) {
        if (b.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            while (b.charAt(i + 1) == ' ') {
                b.deleteCharAt(i + 1);
            }
            result = b.toString(); 
            }
        if (ExpressionTools.isOp(b.charAt(i))) {
            if (i+1 == 0) break;
            else{
                while (ExpressionTools.isOp(b.charAt(i + 1))){
                    b.insert(i+1, ' ');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    String r = b.toString();
    postfix.add(r);

}
```

Comment: `b.charAt(i + 1)` will go out of range when you're at the end of the string, i.e. when `i` equals `b.length() - 1`.

Comment: your condition of `i <  b.length()` will eventually lead to this error (since later the `b.chartAt(i+1)` will reach the length and then one more index)

Comment: It looks like you tried to avoid this problem with `if (i+1 == 0) break`--but how can `i+1==0` ever be true?  Was this a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a loop such as :

```
for (int i = x; i < b.length(); i++)
```

`i` goes from `x` to `b.length()-1`

Therefore, `i+1` would reach `b.length()`, at which point `b.charAt(i + 1)` is out of range and would throw the exception you got.

Answer (score 0):

You loop `i` till `b.length()` and in the `if` condition, you check for char(i+1) which is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

b.charAt(i+1) is causing index out of bound exception for you... As charAt() also start it's counting from zero only...
For eg:

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String s = "Strings are immutable";
      char result = s.charAt(8);
      System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

Output:
a